# How to get into Walker in the Wastes as a level 3 Wizard

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, prestige-class

I am building a Wizard character that focuses on using Greater Drought from the Walker in the Wastes prestige class.  The campaign is starting at level 12, so I need to figure out a way to build a Wizard 3/Walker in the Wastes 9.  I am planning on using Southern Magician and Extra Spell to get around the spell requirement, but I'm having trouble qualifying for Heat Endurance by level 3.

We are using a variant rule where, at every level divisible by 3, we get 3 feats instead of 1. At level 3, I'll have 1 feat from level 1, and 3 feats from level 3.

How can I build a character with 11 total levels of Wizard spellcasting and the Greater Drought Walker in the Wastes ability by level 12?

My current character sheet can be found [here](http://www.myth-weavers.com/sheet.html#id=990524).

Comment: Where is the sticking point in your build? The Heat Endurance feat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sandstorm* has several races in it that gain Heat Endurance as a bonus feat:

- Asheratis
- Bhukas
- Badlands dwarves
- Scablands half-orcs

Since these are racial bonus feats, you do not need to worry about meeting the Fortitude requirement. Any one of them except the half-orc works fine for a wizard.

However, taking one of these races has a problem with Southern Magician—none of them are human. Alternate Source Spell becomes an option, but that’s more costly to take (and if you were dipping a divine class, you could just dip cleric and get the Fortitude anyway). Interestingly, the half-orc is better here: per *Races of Destiny*, a half-human can take things specific to humans (depending on your DM, you may need to take the Human Heritage feat from the same source first, though).

The −2 Int is a problem, though. And since half-orcs never get any love, I’m not sure there’s any way to make a half-orc without the Intelligence penalty (still looking). A Kingdoms of Kalamar supplement, *Fury in the Wastes: The Orcs of Tellene*, includes black orcs that do not have an Intelligence penalty, but no word on what black half-orcs might be like (or whether they’d be compatible with scablands half-orcs). Likewise, *Dragon* vol. 339 updates the Spelljammer races to 3.5 rules and includes the scro, orcs-in-space, and they have no Intelligence penalty, but there is no mention of half-scro.

If you want more cheese, these are all Humanoids. That means *alter self* will let you become one, gaining Heat Endurance. The rules for qualifying for prestige classes say you only need to meet the prerequisites to take the first level—if you can ensure you level-up to 4th while *alter self* is in effect, you are eligible, RAW, to take walker in the waste and then keep its class features and keep taking its levels after *alter self* wears off. Most DMs are unlikely to go for that, though.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the rebuild option in the **Player Handbook II** (pg 197), if allowed.
In short this rule allow you to swap a class level with another untill the non-swapped level still allow you to meet prerequisite to other level.

In your case you could go up to Wiz 12, meet all the prereq, and then swap 9 level to WitW.

I would add that this rule may be not well recived in your party, especially if used in character creation. That said if the party and the gm are ok with it, is probably the "cleanest" way to get to your benchmark.
[here](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=200.0) an example on how strong the rebuild option can be.

Comment: Rebuilding does not let you do anything you couldn't have done originally.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem as presented.

Comment: @KRyan Why not? you go for wiz 6. when you reach it get the feat that you need, next level start WitW. 4 level in WitW and you can swap out 1 wiz level for 1 WitW. when you are at wiz 5 / WitW 6 you can then trade other 2 level of wiz. You can since you don't lower your base Fort bonus under +2 (which would make you lose heat endurance).

Comment: “You can also use this method to trade out (or add in) prestige class levels, though if you want to take levels in a prestige class that’s new to your character, you must be able to demonstrate that he can still qualify for it using what he has gained from his remaining class levels. For example, a 7th-level dwarf fighter couldn’t trade a fighter level for a dwarven defender level, since his remaining fighter levels wouldn’t allow him to meet the +7 base attack bonus requirements for that prestige class.” *Player’s Handbook II* pg. 197.

Comment: I finally got my hands on my copy of the PHII. I double checked the rule about rebuilding. I' m still convinced in the reading i tried to explain, but i noticed that there is a cap to how many level one can switch at once, based on the total character level. That said is still possible by going war 1(or anything else with 2 fort at level 1)/wiz 2/WitW9 and at any point after WitW 6 (wich give you 2 fort) switching the war level to a wiz one. going like this will allow you to use the WitW levels to support the feat. I will rewrite my answer, even if is now useless to avenger is still an option.